# Lost graphical environment in lubuntu (black screen after startx)

Tags: graphics, lubuntu

I hit accept in the upgrade packages dialogue window, locked my screen, and went to a meeting. When I came back after an hour, I couldn't get the screens to light up, and so eventually I rebooted the machine using the power button. It rebooted into text mode.

Upon checking, the packages hadn't upgraded. There was a new kernel in the list, so I thought "why not" and upgraded them all from the shell. Didn't help; still booting in text mode. I have kernels 3.13.0-44, 43, and 32 installed.

`ctrl-alt-f7` just gives me the message that apache2 didn't start within 20 seconds.
`who -r` tells me that I'm in run-level 2.
`startx` isn't doing it - says xinit is unable to connect to the x xerver.

I commented out the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` line in `/etc/default/grub` to get the boot menu (holding down shift keys etc wasn't working). For a single boot in recovery mode on the newest kernel, I could boot to graphical login and desktop environment, but my dual screens had lost their configuration. I reconfigured and rebooted to see if it would stick, but now every boot menu option boots to text mode (including the recovery ones). Oddly, unless I'm booting in recovery mode, the normal boot isn't verbose - it just shows a black screen until I get the login prompt.

The graphics card is an ATI, configured using `amdcccle`.

Any ideas on how I can get my graphical login and desktop back?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the xserver `apt-get install --reinstall xorg`?

Comment: Yes, the xserver still won't output anything other than black screen. I have to `Ctrl-Alt_F1` back to tty1, `ctrl-c` to kill the xserver (dies with return value 2, which isn't promising). I'm starting to wonder if it's fglrx.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be fglrx; I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates` and rebooted. Xserver still wouldn't display anything. (I reinstalled the drivers afterwards)

Comment: Looking through `/var/log/Xorg.1.log`, I see `fglrx: No matching device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:0) found`, whereupon the backtrace log starts and ends with a seg fault and `server aborting` (which would explain it sitting around thinking for a while on boot, before presenting a text login screen). So I have a graphics driver problem, I take it?

Comment: Disabled the ATI card in the BIOS, and then physically removed it. `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*` and `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg xorg; sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg; sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`. Still getting black screen on `startx`, and I get a tiny white window terminal on `xinit`. So it's not the ATI driver (which remains uninstalled for the moment).

Comment: you may have to reinstall/reconfigure your window-manager. If you have only a display-manager and xorg installed properly, you see exactly one window terminal.

Comment: Yeah, just before I left work on Friday it finally understood that the little terminal I see after `xinit` was indeed a graphical window, so the xserver must be working (atp assured me it was installed), so installed lxde (vanilla) and that gives me a desktop when I `startx`. So somehow my xserver and desktop environment got deleted (how?!?!). installing `lxde-ubuntu` didn't work, so I'll have to debug on Monday morning. It's a relatively new installation, so I might just copy $HOME and install afresh. I'm also going to ask for a nvidia card because I've had nothing but instability with fglrx.

Comment: OP gave up and removed the card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up on fixing after every fix lead to the discovery of other odd, worrying problems (see comments stream). Took the graphics card out, and reinstalled the OS after finding that the `xserver` and `lubuntu-desktop` were gone, the ATI driver was spitting out seg faults.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" your own answer (click the little grey check-mark and it'll turn green)